# Match player's entries with difference weight

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a matchmaking system. Currently, what my system does is that it matches the player's entries with the same weight. My target is to match a player's entries with a different weight based on what i will type on my textbox.

For example:

> User  typed "10" on the textbox. Player 1 has 1920 weight. Player 2 has 1930 weight. They will be matched. But If user typed "15" it means that they will not be matched because it exceeds.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-two-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="custom-tabs-two-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-profile-tab">
                     
                                         <div class="card-body table-responsive py-3 px-3">
                            
                                 <table id="entry_list" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                          <input type="text" id="eventID" value="<?php echo $eventID?>">
                                     
                                 <input type="text" name="Difference" id="Difference" placeholder="Difference"> // this textbox is where i need to put whether the difference is 10 or 15.
                                   
                                   
                                    <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                          <th>Entry ID</th>
<!--                                           <th>Event ID</th> -->
                                          <th>Player</th>
                                          <th>weight</th>
<!--                                           <th>Status</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>lightBand</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>wingBand</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>noOfFight</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>score</th> -->
                                       </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                  
                              </div>
                     
                     
                      <button class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal"  data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Match</button>
                     <div class="modal fade" id="createModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <h3 class="modal-title">Matching</h3>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                     </button>
                     
                     
                     
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
   
                     
                      <form id="insertMatching"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >   
                     
                     
        
                                               <input type="text" name="status" id="status">                   
                <h3>Are you sure that you want to match?</h3>
                  
                     
                                    <table id="entry_list1" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" hidden>
                                    
                                    <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                          <th>Entry ID</th>
<!--                                           <th>Event ID</th> -->
                                          <th>Player </th>
                                          <th>weight</th>
<!--                                           <th>Status</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>lightBand</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>wingBand</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>noOfFight</th> -->
<!--                                           <th>score</th> -->
                                       </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                                 
                         
                                 <div id="result"> </div>
                     
            
              
                  <div class="modal-footer">
      
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" id="submitMatching" class="btn btn-primary">Match</button>    
                  </div>
                  
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
                     
                     
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Script(Ajax):

```
<script>

  
let ajaxResult = []; // the pushed data will be saved here
let save_method;
let table;
let base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
let result = [];
var html = "";




// this function combines 2 players with the same weight, if there are entries who has no same weight, hence it'll be joker. (Joker means the player has no match)
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.weight]) {
      const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
      const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
      if (last.length === 2) {
        levelArr.push([curr])
      } else {
        last.push(curr)
      }
    } else {
      acc[curr.weight] = [
        [curr]
      ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};



// this function removes duplicates. Players' entries cannot be matched to themselves. P1 vs P1 is cannot be.
function removeDuplicates(result) {
  return Object.values(result.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.player] = acc[curr.player] || curr;
    return acc;
  }, {}))
}



const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(result);


$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    table = $("#entry_list1").DataTable({


        processing: false,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [],
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        info: false,

        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('entry/ajax_list')?>",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",

             success: function(data) {

                 
                result = combine(removeDuplicates(data.data2));
                  
                
            console.log(result);
                
                var keys = Object.keys(result)
            
                
                
                
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {
  var length_ = val.length;
    val.forEach(function(value, index) {

      var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
      var players = index == 0 ? "playerM[]" : "playerW[]"
      var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
      html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${players}" value="${value.player}">
                 <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                 `
                 
                 
      if (length_ == 1) {
     
        html += `<input type="text" name="entryIDW[]" value="joker"> <input type="text" name="playerW[]" value="joker"><input type="text" name="weightW[]" value="joker">`

      }
    })
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

                
               
              
                

            },
        },

        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0], //first column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            {
                "targets": [-1], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },

        ],
    });
});
  
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi, where is that textbox and you need to make match on change of the textbox ? Also, can you show your json structure ?

Comment: {"draw":"1","recordsTotal":6,"recordsFiltered":6,"data":[["1","wannie1","1910"],["2","wannie1","1915"],["3","wannie1","1920"],["4","wannie2","1920"],["5","wannie2","1930"],["6","wannie2","1930"]],"data2":[{"entryID":"1","player":"wannie1","weight":"1910"},{"entryID":"2","player":"wannie1","weight":"1915"},{"entryID":"3","player":"wannie1","weight":"1920"},{"entryID":"4","player":"wannie2","weight":"1920"},{"entryID":"5","player":"wannie2","weight":"1930"},{"entryID":"6","player":"wannie2","weight":"1930"}]}

I added also my HTML where i need to put the difference. Thank you

Comment: So , on which json result you need to make difference i.e : `result` or the json which you added in your comment ?

Comment: Is it okay in json which i added?

Comment: Can I ask why Entry 3 1915 (Player 1) does not match Entry 1920 (Player 2) or they must different exactly 10 ?

Comment: Because player 1 entry #2 is already matched with player 2 entry #2.  It prioritize the first entry to the last entry of the players. https://prnt.sc/1ylhv31